# Turkish character problem in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

When I search with Turkish characters in elasticsearch, it does not match. For example, when I type "yazilim", the result comes, but when I type "Yazılım", no result. The correct one is "Yazılım".

My index code.

```
 var createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(INDEX_NAME).Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()
                  .Properties(pprops => pprops
                      .Text(ps => ps
                          .Name("Title")
                          .Fielddata(true)
                          .Fields(f => f
                              .Keyword(k => k
                                  .Name("keyword")))))
      )).Settings(st => st
          .Analysis(an => an
              .Analyzers(anz => anz
                  .Custom("tab_delim_analyzer", td => td
                      .Filters("lowercase", "asciifolding")
                      .Tokenizer("standard")
                  )
              )
          )
      );
```

my search query code.

```
var searchResponse = eClient.Search<GlobalCompany>(s => s.Index(INDEX_NAME).From(0).Size(10)
                  .Query(q => q
                  .MultiMatch(m => m
                            .Fields(f => f
                             .Field(u => u.Title)
                             .Field(u => u.RegisterNumber))
                            .Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)
                          .Query(value))));
```

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `asciifolding` filter, it makes sure ASCII characters are used ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html)).

Comment: And neither "Latin Small Letter Dotless I" `ı` nor "Latin Capital Letter I With Dot Above" `İ` are in ASCII

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your field `Title` as a `text` field instead of a `keyword` field and set the `analyzer` for this field to `tab_delim_analyzer`.

I don't know how to translate this in dotNet world but here is what I mean in pure Kibana Dev Console script (curl):

```
DELETE deneme
PUT deneme
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "tab_delim_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom", 
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "tab_delim_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I do it ? can you show me sample code please? @dadoonet

Comment: .Text(ps => ps
                             .Name("Title")
                              .Analyzer("tab_delim_tokenizer")
                              .Fielddata(true)
                              .Fields(f => f
                                  .Keyword(k => k
                                      .Name("keyword")
                                  )
                              )
                          )                                                                                                               If this is what you mean, I tried but it didn't work. @dadoonet

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [deneme/gw1FUQ9RSDib7IhLSaOrVA] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "gw1FUQ9RSDib7IhLSaOrVA",
        "index": "deneme"
      }
    ],
    "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
    "reason": "index [deneme/gw1FUQ9RSDib7IhLSaOrVA] already exists",
    "index_uuid": "gw1FUQ9RSDib7IhLSaOrVA",
    "index": "deneme"
  },
  "status": 400
}   I got such an error.

Comment: I have an index called deneme.

Comment: Updated. Note that this will remove all the data in `deneme` index.